# What is the difference between move and adjoin approach?

Tags: syntax, movement

In Generative grammar, when it comes to the theories of "move" and "adjoin", I am often confused with the usages of these two different approaches.

My understanding is that for *move* approach, it leaves a trace in the original position and moves to another position which projects dotted lines in the tree.

However, for *adjoin* approach, it does not leave a trace and does not project in the tree which is shown as dotted lines.

For example, sentence (1) shows the movement approach but sentence (2) shows the adjoinment.

(1) *What* do you like (t1)?

(2) The apple, I like it.

In (1) *what* is moved from the complement of *like* while in (2), *the apple* is adjoined to the C position as a topic. (??)

Could anyone help me clarify it please? Maybe a few examples would help.

Comment: Maybe it is the same thing.